# In switch statement default always run first

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

As I use break the expected result is stop of switch execute after company name found but in any case default run first and delete my link created from case. I can't understand reason.

Expected result: 
  1)If: var company = Companyname1
  2) link= id="exact_link" href="https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/MenuPortal.aspx?*Division*=1" target="_blank" class="w3-button w3-red">Открыть в Exact NL

The result:
 1) If: var company = Companyname1
 2) link = id="exact_link" target="_blank" onclick="function(){ alert("No client in Exact"); }" class="w3-button w3-red">Открыть в Exact NL

```js
var companyMP = document.getElementsByClassName("_3vY7v2kjExcEpZ9m7ESYyW _3YWV3pFR0CN67Wsv40gDNn _3UGVE08RTYb-pG_1EHBWV1 y1g82IMXa_-RDPNXPcDPm");
 for (var i = 0; i < companyMP.length; i++) {
  var alertnocompany = function(){ alert("No client in Exact"); }
  var company = companyMP[i].innerText;
  switch (String(company)) {
   case "Companyname1":
    document.getElementById('exact_link').href = 'https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/MenuPortal.aspx?_Division_=1';
    break;
   case "Companyname2":
     document.getElementById('exact_link').href = 'https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/MenuPortal.aspx?_Division_=2';
     break;
   case "Companyname3":
     document.getElementById('exact_link').href = 'https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/MenuPortal.aspx?_Division_=3';
     break;
   case "Companyname4":
     document.getElementById('exact_link').href = 'https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/MenuPortal.aspx?_Division_=4';
     break;
   case "Companyname5":
     document.getElementById('exact_link').href = 'https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/MenuPortal.aspx?_Division_=5';
     break;
   default:
     document.getElementById('exact_link').onclick = alertnocompany;
     document.getElementById('exact_link').removeAttribute("href");  
     break;  
  }
 }
```

```css
.w3-button {width:200px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<a id="exact_link" href="" target="_blank" class="w3-button w3-red">Открыть в Exact NL</a>
```

Comment: How do you know the `default` case runs?

Comment: because after click on button I get alert alertnocompany = function(){ alert("No client in Exact"); } and also href deleted from button.

Comment: If I delete default from script all work as expected and link changed according to case logic

Comment: Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please edit your question to include the exact behavior you have, and the behavior you expect.

Comment: That means that `var company = companyMP[i].innerText` doesn't match any `case` you got.

Comment: But in case I delete default: code work and href will be changed

Comment: Because you loop over and are setting the same link.... so if one does not match it replaces it. Your logic is flawed, not the code.

Comment: Anyway you true. In case I change var company = "Companyname1" code work as expected, default not run